# JavaFX ListView and MouseEvent

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a ListView and I want it to change the selected item when I click a different item. For example, I have:

```
result.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

I want to change that `.select(0)` to `.select(x)`, where x is the index on that ListView, from a mouse click. I'm not sure if I explained it correctly.

Hope you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of a ListView is to select the item the user clicks.  There is nothing you need to code to achieve this.

Just run the following sample and click on the list items and you will see the selection change.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewViewer extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Single", "Double", "Suite", "Family App");
        list.setItems(items);
        list.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(list));
        stage.show();

        list.requestFocus();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't work, because I'm using that line of code and .select() requires an int..

Comment: The ListView selection mechanism works... if it doesn't do what you expect, you need to edit your question and clarify.